# New to XML and stuck

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, xml-parsing

Good evening one and all. I am newer to XML and have spent a large chunk of today trying to figure out what exactly this code is doing. I spent a lot of my time testing/rewriting what I was provided on Free Online XSL Transformer (XSLT) - FreeFormatter.com. But I am officially stuck

We utilize a tool that can ingest XML feeds, albeit I am new to XML I can usually fix somethings to work but not tonight.
I have to write a translation that will translate my XML with an XLS file. The XLS is where I am stuck.

Issues as follow:
I have multiple ReportHost and only ONE Report
When I run the following code through the transformer I do not get ANY of the information for Host-IP, Host-FQDN, System-type, Operating-system that are in my variable call outs. I can see the data in the XML thats feeding it but just NOT in my output. Any and all help is always greatly appreciated!

XLS as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="NessusClientData_v2">
 <ArcherRecords>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Report" />
 </ArcherRecords>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report">

<xsl:for-each select="ReportHost">

<xsl:variable name="a" select="@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="host" select="/NessusClientData_v2/Report/ReportHost[@name=$a]"/>

<xsl:variable name="x" select="host-ip"/>
<xsl:variable name="y" select="host-fqdn"/>
<xsl:variable name="z" select="system-type"/>
<xsl:variable name="os" select="operating-system"/>

<xsl:variable name="extract_ip" select="$host/HostProperties/tag[@name=$x]"/>
<xsl:variable name="extract_netbios" select="$host/HostProperties/tag[@name=$y]"/>
<xsl:variable name="extract_type" select="$host/HostProperties/tag[@name=$z]"/>
<xsl:variable name="extract_operating-system" select="$host/HostProperties/tag[@name=$os]"/>

<xsl:for-each select="ReportItem">
   <ArcherRecord>
   
<IP><xsl:value-of select="$extract_ip/text()"/></IP>
<Device_Name><xsl:value-of select="$extract_netbios/text()"/></Device_Name>
<Device_Type><xsl:value-of select="$extract_type/text()"/></Device_Type>
<Operating_System><xsl:value-of select="$extract_operating-system/text()"/></Operating_System>

<port><xsl:value-of select="@port"/></port>
<svc_name><xsl:value-of select="@svc_name"/></svc_name>
<protocol><xsl:value-of select="@protocol"/></protocol>
<raw_severity><xsl:value-of select="@severity"/></raw_severity>
<pluginID><xsl:value-of select="@pluginID"/></pluginID>
<pluginName><xsl:value-of select="@pluginName"/></pluginName>
<pluginFamily><xsl:value-of select="@pluginFamily"/></pluginFamily>
             
<xsl:variable name="extract_port" select="@port"/>
<xsl:variable name="details" select="/NessusClientData_v2/Report/ReportHost/ReportItem[@port=$extract_port]"/>

             <solution><xsl:value-of select="$details/solution/text()"/></solution>
     <risk><xsl:value-of select="$details/risk_factor/text()"/></risk>
             <description><xsl:value-of select="$details/description/text()"/></description>
             <output><xsl:value-of select="$details/plugin_output/text()"/></output>                 
<cvss_temporal_score><xsl:value-of select="$details/cvss_temporal_score/text()"/></cvss_temporal_score>
<cvss_base_score><xsl:value-of select="$details/cvss_base_score/text()"/></cvss_base_score>
<cpe><xsl:value-of select="$details/cpe/text()"/></cpe>
<cve><xsl:value-of select="$details/cve/text()"/></cve>
   </ArcherRecord>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
                 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Snippet of the XML

```html
<NessusClientData_v2>
<Report name="CCRI Network Scan" xmlns:cm="http://www.nessus.org/cm">
<ReportHost name="1328.1527.1142.128">
<HostProperties>
<tag name="LastAuthenticatedResults">1450111187</tag>
<tag name="Credentialed_Scan">true</tag>
<tag name="policy-used">b4c1a0418/FSO Scan Policy</tag>
<tag name="patch-summary-total-cves">2</tag>
<tag name="cpe">cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel</tag>
<tag name="os">linux</tag>
<tag name="smb-login-used">so</tag>
<tag name="ssh-fingerprint">SSH-2.0-Cisco-1.25
</tag>
<tag name="cpe-0">cpe:/o:cisco:ios:15.1 -&gt; Cisco IOS 15.1</tag>
<tag name="mac-address">e0:129:82:d1
00:</tag>
<tag name="system-type">router</tag>
<tag name="operating-system">CISCO IOS 15.1(2)SG6</tag>
<tag name="ssh-auth-meth">password</tag>
<tag name="ssh-login-used">sagalliano</tag>
<tag name="local-checks-proto">ssh</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-5">1338.13357.1342.138</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-4">1383.1357.1342.31</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-3">1338.1632.1356.2337</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-2">1538.3237.24.138</tag>
   <tag name="traceroute-hop-1">1358.2433.2333.252</tag>
    <tag name="traceroute-hop-0">1538.2433.331.1330</tag> 
    <tag name="HOST_END">Mon Dec 14 16:39:47 2015</tag>
   <tag name="host-ip">14138.12457.12442.118</tag>
    <tag name="HOST_START">Mon Dec 14 16:36:31 2015</tag>
   </HostProperties>
```

Requested Output

```html
 <ArcherRecord>
          <IP />
          <Device_Name />
          <Device_Type />
          <Operating_System />
          <port>0</port>
          <svc_name>general</svc_name>
          <protocol>tcp</protocol>
          <raw_severity>0</raw_severity>
          <pluginID>47864</pluginID>
          <pluginName>Cisco IOS Version</pluginName>
          <pluginFamily>CISCO</pluginFamily>
          <solution>n/a</solution>
          <risk>None</risk>
          <description>The remote host is running IOS, an operating system for Cisco routers.
```

Comment: Please post XML file and desired results. Additionally, XSL is distinctly different from XLS. We do not want to confuse a stylesheet script with the earlier Excel file data type.

Comment: Updated all of that information.

Comment: Your content do not relate. XSL script runs a `for-each` on ReportItem which is not shown in XML snippet nor are any if its children and attributes. Also, requested output cannot be reproduced from example XML. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The idea is I should take your code with example to reproduce issues/errors.

Comment: It would be helpful to use indention for all your examples.  Usually children are indented further to the right than the parent nodes (like how your first template is).  This makes it easier for anybody reading it to see the structure.  Most code editors can do this for you automatically (it is often called "pretty printing").  This makes it easier for us to understand what you have provided.

Comment: I can see one issue with your XSLT. You have defined a variable like so: `<xsl:variable name="x" select="host-ip"/>`. However, this sets `x` to the value of the element named `host-ip`, of which there is none. It looks like you actually want to set `x` to the literal value "host-ip", so you really need to do this instead: `<xsl:variable name="x" select="'host-ip'"/>`. (Note the extra single quotation marks around the text).